# Using a 555 instead of 7555

Tags: timer, 555

I'm creating [this circuit](http://web.archive.org/web/20190125025921/http://www.electrokits.com/Telephone/Mobile-Phone-Call-Detector) ([original circuit source here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203062058/http://www.redcircuits.com/Page47.htm)) and it requires a 7555 timer. A 7555 timer is like the next generation 555 since it is CMOS. Now there are no 7555s or CMOS 555 in my area and was wondering what will happen if I replace it with the NE555? Are there any consequences? Will it behave in the same manner? What would be the best thing to do?

**Edit**

Seems like in order to use NE555, adjustments must be made. What are they?

Comment: The 555 suffers from terrible disruptions to the supply voltage for the entire circuit when it switches. I will never use a TTL 555 again. CMOS is the way to go. I ordered some ICM7555 and ICM7556 (dual version) from Mouser but they are backordered until August! Hard to understand why; there ought to be lots of demand for these devices!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NE555, being TTL has a minimum input voltage of 4.5V.  It won't work on the 1.5V that your referenced circuit uses.  That said, I see no reason why you couldn't use an NE555 at 5V, provided that you adjust the values of R2, R3, and add 5 diodes (3.5V worth) in series with the LED.

Comment: Ok so in order to use ne555, resistrs need to be adjusted, hw about the cpacitnce? And other stuff

Comment: Actually, R3 does not need to be adjusted. R2 needs to be adjusted to bias the transistor for maximum sensitivity. The collector voltage needs to sit just above Vcc/3 when there's no signal. And C3 and D2 at the output can be eliminated. Just connect the LED to pin 3 through a suitable resistor.

Comment: The NE555 is not a TTL device. In fact, in terms of traditional bipolar digital logic devices, it isn't a logic device.  The Trigger and Threshold inputs are analog comparators, the output stage has a huge cross-conduction spike typical of an over-biased class AB circuit, and three of the four output transistors never saturate.  The flipflop in the middle of it all is not a saturating-switch latch circuit; it is a linear amplifier with positive feedback (R7).